# Cohomology group $H^n(G, \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})$ as a continuous group or a Lie group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, lie-groups, group-cohomology

**Is there any example of Borel cohomology group $H^n(G, \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})$ for any $G$ 
such that $H^n(G, \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})$ is a continuous group? Such as a Lie group?**

Most of the examples I know, are $H^n(G, \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})$ are simply $\mathbb{Z}_N$ or $\mathbb{Z}$ and/or products of cyclic groups. For example, I know that $H^2(SO(3), \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}_2$, $H^3(SO(3), \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}$. Let us consider the case that $H^n(G, \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})$ for $n>0$.

p.s.  Najib Idrissi's comment raises a good point that $H^0(G, \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}=U(1)$. This example is a trivial counter example. So let us consider and focus on $n>0$ case only. Many thanks.

p.s.2 - I mean the Borel group cohomology studied in, for example [here in condensed matter phyiscs](http://arxiv.org/abs/1106.4772) and [here in a field theory language](http://arxiv.org/abs/1405.7689). Please look at their TABLEs.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, the $0$th cohomology group of a point $H^0(\{*\}, \mathbb{R/Z})$ is equal to $\mathbb{R/Z}$, which is a Lie group.

Comment: $H^n(G,\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})$ is a $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$-module. So your statements are not correct.

Comment: @  Najib Idrissi , I add a condition $n>0$ to be precise.

Comment: Then what about $H^1(S^1, \mathbb{R/Z}) = \mathbb{R/Z}$? And more generally $H^n(S^n, \mathbb{R/Z}) = \mathbb{R/Z}$.

Comment: @QuangHoang But $\mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Z}$ is not a ring, so what is an $\mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Z}$-module supposed to be?

Comment: One can still have $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ coefficients even if it is not a ring, the cohomology will lack a ring structure. But why is $H ^ 3(SO(3),\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}) = \mathbb{Z}$? The singular cohomology is just $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$. What kind of cohomology groups are you looking at?

Comment: @ZhenLin thanks for correction.

Comment: @ apurv, I am looking at Borel cohomology group.

Comment: What is Borel cohomology? Can you give a reference to a definition? Right now I can think of maybe five things that notation could mean.

Comment: (In particular, you don't mean "Borel-Moore cohomology," because there is no such thing as Borel-Moore cohomology. You might mean compactly supported cohomology, but that isn't consistent with the computations you give. Probably you mean some form of group cohomology, but again, I can think of maybe five things you could mean by that.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I think I at least know what you mean now. Let me list the five things you could have meant by $H^n(G, \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})$ (none of which have anything to do with Borel-Moore homology). Below I will write $U(1)$ instead of $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$.

1. The group cohomology of $G_{\delta}$ with coefficients in $U(1)_{\delta}$, where $G_{\delta}$ denotes $G$ with the discrete topology. This is equivalently the cohomology of the classifying space $BG_{\delta} \cong K(G_{\delta}, 1)$ with coefficients in $U(1)_{\delta}$.
2. The cohomology of $BG$ with coefficients in $U(1)_{\delta}$. Presumably this is what Najib Idrissi thought you meant.
3. The cohomology of $BG_{\delta}$ with coefficients in $U(1)$, where $U(1)$ retains its usual topology. This is equivalently the set of homotopy classes of maps from $BG_{\delta}$ to $B^n U(1) \cong B^{n+1} \mathbb{Z}$, or also equivalently $H^{n+1}(BG_{\delta}, \mathbb{Z})$. This one was probably the least likely.
4. The cohomology of $BG$ with coefficients in $U(1)$, where $U(1)$ retains its usual topology. This is equivalently the set of homotopy classes of maps from $BG$ to $B^n U(1) \cong B^{n+1} \mathbb{Z}$, or also equivalently $H^{n+1}(BG, \mathbb{Z})$.
5. The [Borel cohomology](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/stasheff5.pdf), which is the cohomology of a cochain complex constructed like the usual cochain complex computing group cohomology, except that the cocycles $G^n \to U(1)$ are required to be Borel measurable.

(Maybe I should've just known that you meant the last thing, but I didn't know that it existed before googling it carefully. This is not a thing that mathematicians learn about by default.)

If I'm reading [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0040938377900490) correctly (in particular the proof of Corollary 1.14), then in this case options #4 and #5 are isomorphic. In any case this agrees with the computations you've given already (see [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/75389/group-cohomology-of-compact-lie-group-with-integer-coeffient) for the integral cohomology of $BSO(3)$). But I think the five options are genuinely different from each other in general.

In any case, if I'm right that options #4 and #5 are isomorphic in this case, then I believe that for a compact connected Lie group $G$,

> $H^n(BG, U(1)) \cong H^{n+1}(BG, \mathbb{Z})$ is always a finitely generated abelian group, hence a product of $\mathbb{Z}$s and cyclic groups.

So the answer to the question is no. Incidentally, $H^0(BG, U(1)) \cong H^1(BG, \mathbb{Z})$ is not $U(1)$; instead it is the group $\text{Hom}(\pi_0(G), \mathbb{Z})$. So that's not a counterexample either.

Comment: @ Qiaochu Yuan +1, thanks so much for the nice answer. I mean the Borel group cohomology studied in, for example [here in condensed matter phyiscs](http://arxiv.org/abs/1106.4772) and [here in a field theory language](http://arxiv.org/abs/1405.7689). Look at their TABLEs.

Comment: @mystery: okay, so that should be option #5. (But note that one of the authors of that paper asked various questions on MO about these cohomology groups, and the calculations from those MO questions are cited, and in those questions it was never clarified exactly which cohomology the author wanted. So there's still some possible ambiguity here.)

Comment: Hi Qiaochu, thanks for the nice answer. In that case, is that **Borel cohomology different from Borel-Moore cohomology** [in this Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Moore_homology)?

Comment: @mystery: it's completely different. First, the term is "Borel-Moore homology"; it's a version of homology, not a version of cohomology. Second, it applies to spaces, not just (the classifying spaces of) groups.

Comment: @ Qiaochu, your response is rewarded as an answer.